# Stripe payment SCA

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, phalcon

My current Stripe code is as below: as I pass to stripe.
Had been using following Stripe Library:

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php

Its working fine as of now. Now I need to change code according to SCA. But I am total lost with code update.

My controller

```
$this->stripe_->add_charge_array($stripe_user_id, $order_info, $price * 100, $currency, $metadata);

$this->stripe_->pay($currency_id, , $stripeToken, $card_id);

$data = $this->stripe_->get_charge_response($stripe_user_id, , $order_id);

$order->setStripeChargeId($data['charge_id']);//Here I save to db
```

And in stripe library:

```
public function pay($currency_id, $stripe_token = null, $card_id = null, $account_id = null){

    $charge = $this->charge_card($cart['amount'], $cart['currency'], $stripe_token, $description, $cart['metadata'], $currency_id, $account_id);

}
```

And my charge_card method connecting to Stripe

```
public function charge_card(){
 try {
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($STRIPE_KEY);

            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                "amount" => intval($amount),
                "currency" => $currency,
                "source" => $stripe_token, // obtained with Stripe.js
                "description" => $description,
                "metadata" => $metadata
            ));

        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
            // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            // yourself an email
            $result = self::put_stripe_error($e);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            self::put_stripe_error($e);
        }

        return $charge;


}
```

Stripe library:
https://js.stripe.com/v3/

From what I did understand from documentation is that I need to change my charge_card method like below.

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'payment_method' => '{{PAYMENT_METHOD_ID}}',
    'customer' => '{{CUSTOMER_ID}}',
    'amount' => 1099,
    'currency' => 'gbp',
    'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
    'confirm' => true,
    'setup_future_usage' => 'off_session',
]);
```

But then I get payment method Id in $intent . How to proceed from here.
Documentation misses this.

Comment: There are two ways to do this, the quick way, where you create a Payment Intent, return it to your front-end, and complete processing of the Payment there. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/web

If you want a flow most similar to your current charge flow, look at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/web-manual, the 'manual' way, which is a bit more work.

Comment: Did you read: https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication ? You should also point out if this is a one-time payment or not in your question.

Comment: You need to check if the response has requires_action. If so return the response to JS. You need to return the response to your JS. It should be handled  in handleCardAction method. You need to pass payment_intent_client_secret that you received. JS will then trigger sca screen and upon success, it will return back to your post url.